# Why Jquery load method not working laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I use .load on jquery on laravel, but when I use it, why doesn't the page load automatically.

I have to refresh the page, so the page can change.

whereas before I used the native method php .load it works well

Are there any changes that I should make in Laravel?

here is my code:

my route :

```
Route::get('/tiket', 'tiketController@index');
Route::post('/tiket/save_tiket', 'tiketController@saveTiket');
Route::get('/tiket/get_antrian', 'tiketController@getAntrian');
Route::post('/tiket/print', 'tiketController@print');
```

my code jquery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#load_antrian').load('tiket/get_antrian');

    // antrian umum 
    $("#simpan_antrian").on('click',function(){ 
        $.ajax({ 
            url   : "tiket/save_tiket",
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type  : "POST",
            cache : false,
            success: function(msg){ 
                if(msg=="Sukses"){ 
                    $('#load_antrian').load('pages/beranda/getAntrian.php').fadeIn("slow");

                    $.ajax({
                        url : "tiket/print",
                        type: "POST",
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                        {
                            // alert('Silahkan ambil nomor antrian Anda')
                            $.gritter.add({
                                // (string | mandatory) the heading of the notification
                                title: 'Terima Kasih..',
                                // (string | mandatory) the text inside the notification
                                text: 'Silahkan Ambil Nomor Antrian Anda.',
                                class_name: 'gritter-warning' + (!$('#simpan_antrian').get(0).checked ? ' gritter-light' : '')
                            });

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }); 
    });
}); 
</script>
```

my code in controller :

```
public function getAntrian(){

            // fungsi untuk mengambil tanggal hari ini
            $tanggal_hari_ini = gmdate("Y-m-d", time()+60*60*7);

            // fungsi query untuk menampilkan data dari tabel antrian
            $lastAntrianNo = DB::table('data_antrian')->where('tanggal', '=', $tanggal_hari_ini)->max('no_antrian');

            echo "Antrian Terakhir: ". $lastAntrianNo;
    }
```

Comment: You are looking to refresh after #simpan_antrian is clicked ?

Comment: yeah right, that's what i mean, is there a solution to my problem

Comment: Why are you using `$('#load_antrian').load('pages/beranda/getAntrian.php').fadeIn("slow");` ?